# Can Riveteers Overlook go in a red and black Commander deck?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-commander, mtg-color-identity

Can I include [Riveteers Overlook](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Riveteers%20Overlook) (or other similar cards) in a Commander deck with a red and black Commander? I know the rules regarding color identity, but Riveteers Overlook specifically names Mountain, Swamp, and Forest land types:

> When Riveteers Overlook enters the battlefield, sacrifice it. When you do, search your library for a basic Swamp, Mountain, or Forest card, then put it onto the battlefield tapped, then shuffle and you gain 1 life.

Does this include the associated colors in the card's color identity, or can I use this to fetch a Swamp or Mountain and ignore the Forest keyword?

I know that this rule exists:

> 903.5d A card with a basic land type may be included in a Commander deck only if each color of mana it could produce is included in the commander’s color identity.

But as the card does not *have* the basic land type I did not know if this rule affected it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**You can play Riveteers Overlook in any commander deck.**

When rule 903.5d says "A card with a basic land type", it is referring to a card with a basic land type in its type line. This includes the standard basic lands, plus some non-basic lands such as [Blood Crypt](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Blood%20Crypt). Riveteers Overlook does not have any basic land types in its type line; it just mentions them in its text box, so it is not affected by that rule and it can be played in a commander deck with a commander of any color identity.